# Return post with most votes using end_of_day function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to implement a "Post of the day" function. I am thinking of using the end_of_day function. Basically i want the post with the highest votes from the previous day to be used as the quote of the day for the next day (if that makes any sense). I dont think this is the best way to do it so i am open to suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Show us some code please

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off adding a `DATE` column to that table and then selecting using a straight-forward query:

```
@top_10_posts = Post.where(:created_date => date).order('votes DESC').limit(10)
```

You'd assign a value to `created_date` during the `before_save` phase and would have an index:

```
add_index :posts, [ :created_date, :votes ]
```

The `end_of_day` function is only really useful when working with times. Since you're working with dates, it's mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Do you want the votes column to have the date column instead of the posts?

Comment: In this case there's a `votes` column, but if you have votes as separate records, you'd put the date there for grouping reasons.